# How to remove residual flavours from, e.g., a coffee press

Tags: flavor, cleaning, utensils

I'm considering using a glass coffee-press jug as a mixing vessel for other drinks but I'm worried about residual coffee flavour even after using normal detergent.

Is this something I should be worried about, and how would you clean the pot so as to remove any residual flavour?

Comment: What material(s) are we talking about and do you intend to use just the carafe or the other parts as well?

Comment: Thanks for replying, Stephie - just thinking of the glass jar itself. Not the filter part.

Comment: Bleach it with chlorine bleach.

Comment: vinegar should do it, no ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The glass jar should be mostly residue-free due to the smooth surface.

Sometimes slight traces remain when the jar is hand-washed but the harsher detergents usually used in dishwashers should get rid of them easily. (Side note: Don't do this to the coveted stained teapot of a true tea aficionado...)

The other parts are a different issue: often, they are not dishwasher safe and there are plenty of tiny nooks and crannies where coffee residue might "hide" and cling to and impart the characteristic coffee flavour - especially in combination with alcohol, which acts as a solvent.

If you are planning on using only the jar for your martinis, run it trough the dishwasher, give it an extra rinse with clear water just to be sure there is no trace of detergent and cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Glass is very non-porous and should generally not retain any flavor or odor. A good wash with hot soapy water and a very good rinsing should take care of the issue.